# Tag products on Facebook: Direct link to shop?

Tags: links, facebook, tags, products

There is a new featured recently released by Facebook which allows you to add products to a Facebook page, and lets you tag them in images. ( https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1655062744733202 )

Adding this has been pretty easy for me, however whenever I tag a product, it shows up as a modal box on Facebook where it has the information about the product. I noticed other pages have the exact same product information, however when clicking on these, it immediately redirects you to the the website, instead of staying on a Facebook page.

Does anyone know how to set it up so the user gets send to the website?

Answer (score 1):

> Check Out on Another Website: a shop that sends customers to your
>   website to complete their purchase.
>
> Here's how to add this shop type to your Page:
>
> 1. On your Page, click the Shop tab. If you don't see the Shop tab, click your Page Settings, then click Edit Page. Next, click the Add a
>      Tab button and click Add Tab next to the Shop option. You should see
>      the Shop tab on your Page now. If you agree to our Merchant Terms and
>      Policies, check the I agree to the Merchant Terms and Policies box,
>      then click Continue. You may be prompted to reenter your Facebook
>      password for security purposes.
> 2. Choose Check Out on Another Website to send your customers to a website you choose to complete their purchase. Then, click Continue.
> 3. Choose the currency you want to use. This currency will apply to all your products and can't be changed unless you delete your shop
>      section and create a new one.
> 4. Click Save.

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/912190892201033)

Comment: Is there an update on this? I have a shop but I can't find the option to Check Out On Another Website?